# Regular topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be regular, and $A \subset X$ closed. Show that
$\cap\{U \mid U\ \text{is open and}\ A\subset U\}$.

I know that a space is regular if each $x\in X$ and closed set $A$ not containing x have disjoints nbds; that is, if A is closed and $x\not\in A$ then there is a nbd $U$ of $x$ and an open $A\subset V$ such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your question is asking us to prove that the set
$$
\mathscr U:=\bigcap\{U\subseteq X\mid \text{$U$ is open and $A\subseteq U$}\}
$$
equals $A$.
It's clear that $A\subseteq\mathscr U$, so we need only show $\mathscr U\subseteq A$.

Suppose $x\not\in A$. Then there exists disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $A\subseteq U$ and $x\in V$. Hence $x\not\in U$, which implies $x\not\in\mathscr U$. This proves $A^c\subseteq\mathscr U^c$, so we conclude $A=\mathscr U$.